shortkeys in winedt 11
I just upgrade to Winedt11
I would like to change somme shortkeys.
For instance, one among plenty, I want alt-T lauching LaTeX in place of Ctrl-L
and alt-d launching dvi in place of f8
As I read, I went into "...Roaming....mainmenu.ini" change in line 3560
MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\LaTeX.edt');"
SHORTCUT="16460::Ctrl+L"
with Alt+T and of course ... as usual ... nothing change !
alt-T continues to open "tools"menu and latex compilation continues to be launch with "ctrl-L"
What must i do ?

WinEdt is one of a Text editor as like as NotePad++, Epsilon and EMacs, so this question is not suits here

As in my old winedt5.9 i redefine  F1 as  Ins('$$');CMD('Char Left') and nothing happened, "F1" continue to launch "help".
Really extremely anoying

@MadyYuvi Some questions about using an editor with LaTeX support are on-topic. It is probably a bit of a borderline case whether questions about changing a shortcut to start LaTeX are on-topic or off-topic. In fact, I would recommend asking the question directly in the WinEdt forum. And it seems this already happened: https://github.com/WinEdt-Team/WinEdt-Support/discussions/61

if you want to reassign alt+T you will have to disable this shortkey for the main menu, so change MENU="&Tools" to MENU="Tools".
